# How to load a 16bit (rgb565) bmp into a byte array with c# standard

Tags: c#, bitmap, bmp

So I had this bit of code, that works great in my windows c# application or a framework DLL.

```
        private static Icon? LoadSync(string filepath)
        {
            Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

            BmpBitmapDecoder decoder = new BmpBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];

            if (bitmapSource.Format != System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgr565)
            {
                Debug.Print($"Image at path `{filepath}` is not RGB565!");
                return null;
            }

            byte[] icon = new byte[bitmapSource.PixelHeight * bitmapSource.PixelWidth * sizeof(short)];

            bitmapSource.CopyPixels(icon, bitmapSource.PixelWidth * sizeof(short), 0);

            return new Icon() { Width = (ushort)bitmapSource.PixelWidth, Height = (ushort)bitmapSource.PixelHeight, Data = icon };
        }
```

It loads a 16 bit .bmp file into memory, and then gives the pixels to me in the form of a byte array.

However, I encountered a weird compile bug, and my online searches seemed to turn up that it was caused by some odd difference in how a function is declared as an extension method in one instance, but an actual member in another. I forget the details but the proposed solution was to switch to a standard dll from framework. I tried it and it fixed my problem.

But now, reintroducing the above code, I no longer have access to `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`. So I'm wondering what options I have to be able to accomplish the same thing.

Using the plain old bitmap library, the data is converted to (I think) rgb888 without any option to preserve the format.

If you're wondering why I need a byte array, I'm sending the data on to an arduino with a screen.

Comment: Never knew it had a bug.. I normally would go for the .net framework library, but...What format is it saved?

Comment: The supported 16-bit colour types in `System.Drawing` are `Rgb565`, `Rgb555` and `Argb1555` (as little-endian `Int16` blocks). So it should not convert that data. You can check this on the `PixelFormat` property of your image object. You can use `LockBits` and `Marshal.Copy` to get the actual bytes out. Do make sure to keep the stride from your `BitmapData` object in mind; length of a line of bytes does not necessarily equal `width * bpp`.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done exactly what you're trying to do, but I did recently have to work with images in some C# code. I added the System.Drawing NuGet package and made use of the Image class. This might be a help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=windowsdesktop-5.0